# What is the probability that there is no card remains at its initial position when a standard 52-card deck is well shuffled?

Tags: probability, card-games

We have a standard 52-card deck. The cards positions are listed, then this 52-card deck was well-shuffled. What is the probability that there is no card remains at its initial position?

Comment: The relevant concept is [Derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability in question  is
$$
\frac {!52}{52!}=\sum_{k=0}^{52}\frac {(-1)^k}{k!}\approx\frac1e,
$$
where $!n $ is the number of permutations of $n $ objects without fixed points also known as [subfactorial](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of $n $.